# MongoDB aggregate and then flatten

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, backend

FULL DISCLOSURE: I'm a MongoDB noob

I'm dealing with a legacy DB structure. A part of my MongoDB looks like this currently:

- Events (_id, name (string), ...)
- Orders (_id, eventId (as string), products (array of {prodIdentifier (string), quantity (number)}), customer_ID (string), signee (string), sign_time (date), ...)
- Products (_id, prodIdentifier (string), price (number), sku (string), ...)

The relations are as follows:

- Event 1..N Orders (via eventId)
- Orders 1..N Products (via products array)

I need to query in a way that given an eventId, I return

> Order ID
>  Customer Name (can be a cascade request / premeditated
> by frontend),
>  Product SKU,
>  Product Name,
>  Quantity,
> Value (quantity * price),
>  Signee Name,
>  Sign time

*Mind that, my interface requires filters and sorts on all of the above fields along with limit and offset for pagination, to reduce query time, fast UI, etc.*

I could use `populate` on orders, but how am I supposed to honor the limit and offset via mongoose then. I'm wondering if I should make a view, in which case how should I flatten it to send/receive a list that honors the limit and offset.

Or will it have to be a very manual, step-by-step build of the resulting list?

UPDATE:

Sample data in the DB:

Event Object:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("6218b9266487367ba1c20258"), 
    "name" : "XYZ", 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-02-03T13:25:43.814+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-02-14T09:34:47.819+0000"),
    ...
}
```

Order(s):

```
[
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("613ae653d0112f6b49fdd437"), 
    "orderItems" : [
        {
            "quantity" : NumberInt(2), 
            "productCode" : "VEO001", 
        }, 
        {
            "quantity" : NumberInt(2), 
            "productCode" : "VEO002", 
        }, 
        {
            "quantity" : NumberInt(1), 
            "productCode" : "VEO003", 
        }
    ], 
    "orderCode" : "1000", 
    "customerCode" : "Customer 1", 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-09-10T05:00:03.496+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-02-08T10:06:42.255+0000"), 
    "eventId" : "6218b9266487367ba1c20258"
}
]
```

Products:

```
[
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604206685f25b8560a1cd48d"), 
    "Product name" : "ABC", 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-03-05T10:22:32.085+0000"), 
    "tag" : "VEO001", 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-03-28T07:29:21.939+0000"), 
    "Product Price" : NumberInt(0), 
    "photo" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6042071a5f25b8560a1cd4a9"), 
        "key" : "e8c9a085-4e8d-4ac4-84e9-bb0a83a59145", 
        "name" : "Screenshot 2021-03-05 at 11.24.50.png"
    }, 
    "name" : "ABC", 
    "_costprice" : NumberInt(12), 
    "_sku" : "SKUVEO001",
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604206685f25b8560a1cd48a"), 
    "Product name" : "DEF", 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-03-05T10:22:32.085+0000"), 
    "tag" : "VEO002", 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-03-28T07:29:21.939+0000"), 
    "Product Price" : NumberInt(0), 
    "photo" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6042071a5f25b8560a1cd4a9"), 
        "key" : "e8c9a085-4e8d-4ac4-84e9-bb0a83a59145", 
        "name" : "Screenshot 2021-03-05 at 11.24.50.png"
    }, 
    "name" : "DEF", 
    "_costprice" : NumberInt(13), 
    "_sku" : "SKUVEO002",
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604206685f25b8560a1cd48a"), 
    "Product name" : "GHI", 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-03-05T10:22:32.085+0000"), 
    "tag" : "VEO003", 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-03-28T07:29:21.939+0000"), 
    "Product Price" : NumberInt(0), 
    "photo" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6042071a5f25b8560a1cd4a9"), 
        "key" : "e8c9a085-4e8d-4ac4-84e9-bb0a83a59145", 
        "name" : "Screenshot 2021-03-05 at 11.24.50.png"
    }, 
    "name" : "GHI", 
    "_costprice" : NumberInt(13), 
    "_sku" : "SKUVEO003",
},
]
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Please provide some sample data

Comment: and also some expected output too

Comment: @nimrodserok please have a look now

Comment: @ray please have a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {$match: {eventId: "6218b9266487367ba1c20258"}},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      localField: "orderItems.productCode",
      foreignField: "tag",
      as: "orderItemsB"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "orderItems": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$orderItemsB",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$orderItems",
                  {"$indexOfArray": ["$orderItems.productCode", "$$this.tag"]}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      orderItemsB: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "orderItemsB"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "events",
      let: {eventId: "$eventId"},
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {$expr: {$eq: [{$toString: "$_id"}, "$$eventId"]}}
        }
      ],
      as: "event"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {event: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$event", 0]}}   
  },
  {$unwind: "$orderItems"}
])
```

As you can see on [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kM48PFd5p0A). This will give you a document for each product of the order with all the data.

Comment: Thanks, thats almost perfect, expect that the ```orderItem``` has lost ```quantity```... I'm trying to fix it, and would appreciate if you have further quick input

Comment: Updated according to the comment

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, appreciate it